# How do I ensure that my enterprise search center only pulls from certain search service application?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, enterprise-search

We have two search service applications - one that searches our local SharePoint sites and another that searches through a fileshare.  I would like for our enterprise search center to only search for files from the fileshare; however, it seems to be also searching our local SharePoint sites (which I assume it's getting from the other search service application because the other one is never set to crawl the local sites).

How can I force the search center to only show results from the search service application that crawls the fileshare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Web Application Service Application Connections. The sites under that web app will use the Search Service App that is selected in the Service Application Connections.

Comment: I ended up finding this out on my own, but thank you nonetheless.